# JavaScript - Chart does not show when is inside a div tag

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to put a JS chart inside a `<div>` but the issue is that when I put it inside the div tag, nothing shows!

I have tried with different libraries ([C3](http://c3js.org/), [AmCharts](https://www.amcharts.com/), [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)) and all of them the same issue, nothing appears when calling the div of the charts inside another div:

```
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

***The below one, does not work :***

```
<div class="block"><div id="chartdiv"></div></div>
```

However, when placing it outside of the div tag, it works. I've tried to debug, but no errors shows on the console!

**CSS of block class:**

```
.block {
display: block;
width: 98%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding-top: 6px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
border-radius: 4px;
background-color: #fff;
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 hsla(0, 0%, 91%, .75);
}
```

There are 5 graphs on the page, and I believe that a conflict of a JavaScript happens which is causing the issue.

Any ideas about what's happening? I am not sure if there is an issue with the library itself; however, if you have charting libraries and that have the ability to show real-time data, please share it.

Comment: What does `class="block"` do? There's nothing magic about wrapping a `<div>` around another `<div>`, but your CSS for class "block" could definitely cause a problem.

Comment: Nothings appears, but did you inspect the element to see if there is some content inside ? That may just be an issue regarding the dimensions of your div elements.

Comment: @Pointy I've posted the CSS. I inspected as you said, I I've found that the graph is there but does not show, I believe that because there are 5 graphs on the page, so maybe it's a javascript issue ?

Comment: If many libraries have the same problem, then it means you are doing something wrong. HTML structure doesn't matter (for Highcharts at least). Do you have your website live? Or can your recreate issue on jsFiddle? Number of charts doesn't matter, see Highcharts example: http://jsfiddle.net/v98mf533/ Make sure your div's IDs are different.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some explicit CSS rules - your HTML may be inheriting something unexpected:

```
.block {
    width: 98%;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 6px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 hsla(0, 0%, 91%, .75);

    /* Sure you don't want inline-block here? */
    display: block !important;
    visibility: visible !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```